# Is the Spark ReduceByKey function optimized by running the reduce function on each partition before the shuffle?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm looking at some of the input and output metrics for my spark tasks.  This is basically a count by key with a saveAsHadoop at the end to store the data into DynamoDB.  A classic - map-reduce.

[image]

Looking at some of the metrics,

[image]
 it appears that after the map, spark blindly shuffles the data, and then applies the reduce function to each shuffled parition.  If the reduce function majorly reduces the output it's optimal to first sort and apply the reduce to each partition before the shuffle and again after, and is easy because the reduce function associates and commutes. This is a classic Hadoop map -> combine -> shuffle -> reduce pattern.  Can Spark take advantage of this optimization?

Answer (score 1):

ReduceByKey:

[image]

In above image you can see that RDD X has set of multiple paired elements like (a,1) and (b,1) with 3 partitions.

It accepts a function `(accum, n) => (accum + n)` which initialize accum variable with default integer value 0, adds up an element for each key and returns final `RDD Y` with total counts paired with key. And **before shuffling** the data across the partitions it does the same `aggregation` locally for each partition.

It is a wide operation as it **shuffles data** from multiple partitions and creates another `RDD`.

Before sending data across the partitions, it also `merges the data locally` using the same associative function for **optimized data shuffling**

[Source](http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-reducebykey-example/)